# Is there a prop that gives me the number of rows for material react table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

useMaterialReactTable

I want to be able to show the number of rows above the table

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the total row count, it's the length of the array you feed to the table. For example, say the array name is "data", then data.length.